# Can a DisplayTemplate displays model in different way if it is a singole object or a collection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ServiceViewModel class.
Someties in my application I have to display a single service, but sometimes I have a list of service.

I use a DisplayTemplate to display the single service in a way like this:

```
<div >
   <strong>Id:</strong> @Model.Id<br />
   <strong>Codice:</strong> @Model.Code<br />
   <strong>Nome:</strong> @Model.Name<br />
</div>
```

I was wondering if is there a way to have the same DisplayTemplate shows a table if the model passed is a collection of services.

Something like this:

```
@if (Model is IEnumerable<ServiceViewModel>)
{
  <table class="table-bordered">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Code</th>
          <th>Name</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
        <tr>
          <td>@item.Id</td>
          <td>@item.Code</td>
          <td>@item.Name</td>
        </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
}
else
{
    <div >
       <strong>Id:</strong> @Model.Id<br />
       <strong>Codice:</strong> @Model.Code<br />
       <strong>Nome:</strong> @Model.Name<br />
    </div>
}
```